# using the return type as pointer to derived class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Is it possible to have a function in base class which will have return type as pointer to derived class? the main objective is for later use where you use `Base` and `Derived` Class to set values.

```
Base B1;
B1.SetName("nameOfBase");
Derived* D1 = B1.CreateDerived("DerivedFromBase");//CreateDerived method will be in class Base
D1->SetMinPoint(0,1);//this method will be implemented in derived class
D1->SetMaxPoint(4,4);//this method will be implemented in derived class
```

I am having problem in implementation, i did something like

```
class Base
{
public:
  Base();
  bool SetName(char*);//or SetName(string)
  Derived* CreateDerived(char*); // or Derived* CreateDerived(string)
  ~Base();
protected:
  char baseName[20];// or string baseName
  Derived* derivedPtr[5];
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  Derived();
  bool SetName(char*);//the name given in Derived* CreateDerived(char*) will be set here
  ~Derived(); 
};
```

when i try to do this and run the program i get errors like

```
// Derived* CreateDerived(char*); // or Derived* CreateDerived(string)
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type identifier: int assumed.
```

Comment: You should look up the Factory Pattern

Comment: why you don't return Base * ? And Base having an array of Derived* 's looks like a weird design I would say

Comment: You don't have `;` after `bool SetName(char*)`

Comment: This code seems to be a bad design for me. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It seems to be a somewhat questionable design, but there's nothing preventing you from doing it. You just need to declare class `Derived` before you refer to it:

```
class Derived;  //forward declaration here

class Base
{
public:
  Base();
  bool SetName(char*);//or SetName(string)
  Derived* CreateDerived(char*); // or Derived* CreateDerived(string)
  ~Base();
protected:
  char baseName[20];// or string baseName
  Derived* derivedPtr[5];
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  Derived();
  bool SetName(char*); //don't forget semi-colon
  ~Derived(); 
};
```

And as @psur mentioned, you were also missing a semi-colon after `SetName`.

And I do strongly suggest using `std::string` instead of `char*` for strings in C++.

Comment: Thats awesome!!!! works perfectly now. Actually i'm doing intern in Bosch. Its quite complicated to explain the entire project. Thanx again for the help. I was wondering around for this problem since yesterday.

Comment: @Biplov13 If this solved your problem, you might want to mark the answer as accepted (using the tick mark button). That's how SO generally works.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make your CreateDerived method pure virtual and override it in the derived classes? The return type of the method in the Base class would be **Base**, but the overridden method in the derived class could return the **Derived** instance you need. I think that is the **Template Method-Pattern**.

Your class inheritance should always behave like an is-a relation (Derived-Class **is-a** Base-Class). I think your design suggestion sort of undermines this rule.

Comment: actually it could be done using virtual function, no doubt. But I was told by my teacher(also client for this project) to achieve to objective as i mentioned, which will not be possible using virtual function. Will it?

Comment: Of course, if you **have to** return the type of a derived class in a base class, my answer is not very helpful. But the approach really looks odd to me.