# returning instance of derived class from base class member function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it an O.K. design if i return an instance of Derived class from Base class member function(created using new Derived()) ?

Also this involves the need to forward declare the Derived class and also make the Derived class constructor public.

Code Sample :-

```
Class Base
{
 public:
  Base() {}
  Derived* get_new_derived(int X) 
  { 
    Derived *der = new Derived(X); 
    return der;  
  }
}

Class Derived : public Base
{
 private:
  int _X;
 protected:
  Derived(int X) { _X = X; }
 public:  
  Derived* get_new_derived(int X) 
  { 
    Derived *der = new Derived(X); 
    return der;  
  }
}
```

I have one more derived class(say Derived1). Now let's say :-

**Usage1 :**

```
Derived1* der1 = new Derived1();
Derived * der = der1->get_new_derived(10);
```

**Usage2 :**

```
Derived1* der1 = new Derived1();
Base* bs = der1;
Derived * der = bs->get_new_derived(10);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific (ideally show a small code sample of the intended interface & usage)? For example, do you mean returning a `new Derived()` typed as `Base*` or as `Derived*`? And in modern C++, you should never use an owning raw pointer - use a smart pointer like `[std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current form. You have working code and you're asking whether it's a good solution, but we don't know the motivating problem.

Comment: Take a look at the comments in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611959/using-the-return-type-as-pointer-to-derived-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, this usually indicates bad design - a base class shouldn't normally know/care about its derived classes.

Note that you can return a pointer to `Derived` typed as `Base*` - that's the principle of the Factory Method design pattern. Perhaps this fits your actual scenario?

Note however that all rules have exceptions. If your (base class + derived classes) represent a tighly coupled and coherent unit (such as a `Tree` interface with two subclasses `FastTree` and `SmallTree`, optimised for different purposes), it is acceptable for them to be aware of each other, and `Tree` defining such functions as:

```
std::unique_ptr<SmallTree> Tree::createSmallCopy() const
{
  return { new SmallTree(/*args*/) };
}

std::unique_ptr<FastTree> Tree::createFastCopy() const
{
  return { new FastTree(/*args*/) };
}
```

So it depends on your actual use case. I'd generally be wary of such design, it but it has its uses.

---

As a side note, in modern C++, you should never use an owning raw pointer - use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Also i want to ask if its common to have a derived class friend of another derived class (both derived from the same base class) ? I am asking this because, i want only one way to instantiate class Derived, and adding a virtual function to Derived1 implies i have to make Derived ctor as public, which defeats my purpose. So is it ok to add Derived as a friend of Derived1 ?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj The same reasoning applies. If they form a tightly coupled & coherent unit, use all means necessary to achieve your desired functionality. In the general case, use `friend` extremely sparingly.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template<class Derived>
class Base
{
  // methods within Base can use template to access members of Derived
};
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
  // ...
};
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. The question is whether you should.

You shouldn't do it since it implies Base knows Derived which isn't proper object oriented design. The dependencies should be one way - derived knows the Base and not vice versa.